# file cant be found on mac but does on windows

Tags: python

I was working on my windows pc on a python(3.7) script where I open a "input.ops" file full of questions and parse it. It was working well until today when I opened the same script on my mac where I would get the error which said that "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './input.ops'".

The way I get the file currently is through

```py
base_location = './'
exs_loc = base_location + 'input.ops'

# Read exercise list
exercise_file = open(exs_loc, 'rb')
file_data = exercise_file.read()
```

The files are all held in the same folder and when I list all the files then I see that none of the files with the .ops extension are displayed. I do not understand why the files are not being recognized and will appreciate any help although I would like to stay away from the solutions that require you to pass the absolute path.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: You're running this code on two different computers, so the obvious answer is that the input file does not exist in the current directory on the mac.  The current directory is not necessarily the same directory where the python script is located.  Try this code `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to see what the current directory actually is.

Comment: I downloaded the most up to date files from git and if I search for the file then I do see it, or do you mean something else by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses a different file naming system than Unix OS (e.g. Mac). So your equivalent file would be `.\input.ops`.

For Python, the best way to deal with this is the `pathlib` module. For your example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

exs_loc = Path('./input.ops')
```

`exs_loc` is now a valid path on both Windows and Mac OS. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for more details!

Edit: This didn't appear to fix the issue, perhaps you're invoking the interpreter (running your python code) from another directory, and so the 'local path' is not correct, try the following:

```py
exs_loc = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / 'input.ops'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have added what you have shown here but I still seem to run into the same error. I am using visual studio code and if I move the file outside of the folder with the scripts then by typing in the command "ls" the file I need appears so there must be something else going on right? Sorry if my explanation is bad, im quite new to this

Comment: `open()` with forward-slashes works perfectly fine on Windows computers.  I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps the directory you are invoking the interpreting from differs from the directory with the `input.ops` file. If the source file (with your shown code) is in the **same directory**, you can use this in instead: `exs_loc = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / 'input.ops'` @DavinciCake

Comment: @JohnGordon didn't know that! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Sooo I have no idea what happened but I tried everyone's suggestions and in the end I removed everything to how it was and it all miraculously works. An explanation is still welcome cause I am confused out of my mind, but thanks for all the help!

Comment: If you post your current file tree (of relevant files) and where you are running the code, I could try and give you an explanation. But perhaps it was just a little typo/mistake that worked itself out :) @DavinciCake